How to start Spring-Cloud-Stream consumer bindings programmatically on application "readiness"?
I'm working on an application where I need to programmatically start the processing of messages. The application uses Spring Cloud Stream with two different binder implementations: one from Solace and another custom implementation of the Spring Cloud Stream binder based on TIBCO Rendezvous.
In my application, it's necessary to load certain data before processing messages, which I achieve by:

Not automatically starting the relevant bindings: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputBinding-in-0.consumer.autoStartup=false
Loading the required data in an ApplicationRunner(Order=0)
In another ApplicationRunner(Order=1), which is invoked after the previous one, starting the bindings using the BindingsLifecycleController: bindingsLifecycleController.start("inputBinding-in-0")

This solution only works if the bindings belong to a group (spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputBinding-in-0.group=group42); otherwise, the bindings cannot be started:
2024-09-24T11:03:11.981+02:00  WARN 12388 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$2 : Can not re-bind an anonymous binding
A brief analysis revealed the cause, which is a limitation in the Spring Cloud Stream implementation: for every consumer binding configured in the application configuration, SCS creates a DefaultBinding where the restartability depends on the definition of the "group":
public class DefaultBinding<T> implements Binding<T> {
...
  public DefaultBinding(String name, String group, T target, Lifecycle lifecycle) {
      Assert.notNull(target, "target must not be null");
      this.name = name;
      this.group = group;
      this.target = target;
      this.lifecycle = lifecycle;
      this.restartable = StringUtils.hasText(group);
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void start() {
      if (this.companion != null) {
          this.companion.start();
      }
      if (!this.isRunning()) {
          if (this.lifecycle != null && this.restartable) {
              this.lifecycle.start();
          } else {
              this.logger.warn("Can not re-bind an anonymous binding");
          }
      }
  }
...
}

Why does the restartability of consumer bindings in Spring Cloud Stream depend on the definition of the group? Shouldn't these be independent of each other?
Additionally, what other possible solutions could be used to start consumer bindings programmatically in case no group is defined?

This is actually by design and in cases when you don't define a group the anonymous group will be created anyway. In production it is advisable to always have a group. It really doesn't hurt to have one. Can you share why are you against it?

The application is built from multiple services; each service has multiple instances running which belong to a fault-tolerant group, in which one acts as the leader: every instance process all messages, but only the leader can respond.
This setup is necessary so that if the leader fails, another one can take over its role without losing previously processed information and to make the switch quick and smooth.
If we assign the consumer bindings to a group, then within a given service instances, the consumer bindings will be assigned to the same group, and only one will receive the messages.

So, you are presenting your design for fault tolerance where all services are processing the same data redundantly. And if I understand correctly only one (leader) can respond and effectively participate in the process. The rest are just spinning with no real outcome. Why? Why not actually benefit from the fault tolerance provided by the consumer groups where data destined to a failed consumer will be redirected to another? I mean you are asking the question under assumption that you have a correct fault tolerance design and you are looking for some accommodation from the framework.

I am not looking for any accommodation from the framework to fix the problems in my fault-tolerant design. I am looking for a solution that allows me to start my consumer bindings programmatically once my services are ready to consume messages. (without setting the group) Above, I have explained why it is not possible to use the workaround you described.

group is an internal concept in Spring Cloud Stream to group consumer instances. It doesn't have to do anything with external services. You can start all the consumer instances in the same group.

Yes, that's correct. In some services, the group is set where a distributed queue concept is needed. However, in other cases, it is not possible to set the group because a different behavior is required, as described above. My problem is that the lifecycle of a consumer binding doesn't allow the programmatic initial startup of the bindings if the group is not set.

From what I understand the processes in question are not stateless, therefore consumer groups - where each message is only received by one member - cannot be used. All instances shall receive all messages and maintain there inner state, but only one sends to an external service.
How would you do that with Spring Cloud Stream?
